# svn: default name for a tag when name is not important?

Tags: svn, tags

I need to tag the current state of my source tree in svn. My problem is I don't care what the name is, I just need to mark the current revision in an immutable* manner. (*subject to malicious behavior)

What's the best way to do this?

```
branches/
tags/
   ???
trunk/
```

should ??? be the date, an incrementing sequence, the repository rev # ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of date and the svn revision number. Its immutable and will allow you to easily find newer commits. You could also put the date in the tag if desired.

Answer (score 0):

Use the revision number, is by definition inmutable.
You can use the revision number in the usual svn commands to access the repository in a particular point in time.

For example, to get revision:
svn co http://my.svn/project1/trunk@1024

Comment: I know how to do that; however I would like to use tags to snapshot a particular version in the `/tags` area so it appears in the HEAD version.